# Is it ethical to ask my employer to shortlist me in a position within company due to loss of deadline application

Tags: hiring, position, company

I have been working as temporary employee while my company is currently in the hiring process for a permanent position of the same role.

I missed the deadline of the application and the feedback, which I have from my managers, is very positive. So my question is, is it ethical to ask my employer if I can be considered as candidate?

Comment: Why do you think it could be unethical?

Comment: Seriously, I would want to hear your explanation what makes you think this would be unethical.

Comment: I hope that is clearly formulated but when I say to "be considered as candidate" I mean since that "I lost the deadline to submit my CV I will ask If I can be considered as shortlisted candidate" . As I explained below I though that can be a bit sneaky of asking to "shortcut" the hiring process so this is the reason of asking.

Comment: Generally speaking companies like to hire internally as opposed to externally. They *have* to post the job, even if they ultimately hire internally. Judging by how reluctant you are to apply, maybe they thought you just weren't interested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is ethical to ask to be considered. Worst case scenario is they say no. Best case scenario you get a new job.

Generally, asking is not a problem. Ethical problems only (potentially) come if you don't accept their answer.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think there is anything unethical about it? You want a job, you ask for it, and if you are the best person for the job you should get it. Not asking and then the company only gets the second best person, now *that* would be unethical.

What would also be unethical would be asking to be considered while offering cash to the manager, or asking the manager while holding a knife to his throat. That's what would be considered unethical. I assume you don't plan to do any of these things?

Comment: I though that can be a bit sneaky of asking to "shortcut" the hiring process but I realise that is not :)

Answer (score 0):

The ethical dilemma is not on your end; the ethical issue is what should the company do.

They set a deadline, and now they are considering allowing an exception to that deadline.

While they do want to make sure they get qualified candidates, they don't want to run the risk that they never make a decision. If they always reopen the system for late applications they can convince themselves that next week the perfect candidate will apply.

They also risk that a candidate will claim the constantly shifting process was discriminatory.

This doesn't mean don't ask. This doesn't mean don't plead for the opportunity to enter the process after the deadline. But do realize that they may say no.